# usb debugging code

Tags: java, android, c, eclipse

I want to interface my HUAWEI U8150 which is an Android 2.2 version with an external device via a USB Interface. Could there be any links or anything to guide me onto assessing the USB code to enhance that communication?

Comment: Show us what you have found already, and you might get more response!  Here's my 2c: http://hackaday.com/category/android-hacks/

Comment: You may want to get this migrated over to http://android.stackexchange.com/. This doesn't really seem like a programming related question so I think you will get more answers over there.

Answer (score 2):

Is the external USB device a USB host, or USB OTG host?

AFAIK Android 2.3.4 does not support being a USB host. In which case the complexity is in the host, because the Android device does not change, it is still a USB device, and the host needs to figure out how to talk to it.

Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html for details if making a USB host

Comment: One way to get around this is to use the Android Accessory development kit and design a custom (hardware) bridge accessory.  The bridge would act as a host and handle communication between the two devices.

Comment: @rhooligan - I don't understand your comment. The link I posted **is** to the Android Accessory development kit, where it explalins options to make a USB HOST to handle comms. I can update my answer, but I don't understand, what extra you are adding?